# Allowing more than 15 digits shown in excel

Tags: vba, excel

i am working on a simple vba excel script. i have encountered some problems as i have removed the number's scientific format using this way

```
Columns("b:ad").NumberFormat = "0"
```

But then i realised that one of the columns is having 23 digits which is longer than 15digits as i need to display all exact 23 digits in excel(I do know the limitations of excel just for 15 digits). example, 23 digits need to be shown is 32097459000000000209640 but the field currently shows 32097459000000000000000. (FYI,i only need 000000000209640)

Any Ideas?

Comment: The only way to do this is to store the 23 digits in the cell as text.

Comment: can you give me some example for this?

Comment: I think this might help u a bit [Convert numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553151/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

## Storing values as text in a cell

### Using VBA

The following will set the formatting in the range as text:

```vb
MyRange.NumberFormat = "@"
```

### Adding an apostrophe at the start of the number

Having a an apostrophe (') at the start of a cell will tell Excel that what you are typing should be considered text.

[image]

### With the Excel interface

You can tell Excel in advance that what you are going to write to the cell is a string. It's important to do it in advance otherwise you might loose digits if Excel interprets the value as a number right after typing it and you won't gain them back even if you change the formatting back to text.

[image]